# FXML file is not being reached

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, fxmlloader

I want to load a GUI using a fxml file. However after multiple attempts into fixing it, it keeps returning that the file is not found and/or that it is null. I have tried to place the file within my Graphics package but that does not work. Here is my path from my project: src/main/java/com/example/javapoker/Graphics/GUI.fxml.

My code:

```
package com.example.javapoker.Graphics;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        // Load the FXML file using getResource() from the class loader
        URL url = getClass().getResource("/com/example/javapoker/Graphics/GUI.fxml");
        String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
        System.out.println("Classpath: " + classpath);

        if (url != null) {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(url);
            primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(loader.load(), 400, 400));
            primaryStage.setTitle("Hello JavaFX");
            primaryStage.show();
        } else {
            System.err.println("Resource 'GUI.fxml' not found");
        }
    }

}
```

Here is my stack trace error:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:119)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1081)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:893)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Location is not set.
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2556)
    at javafx.fxml@20.0.1/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2531)
    at com.example.javapoker/com.example.javapoker.Graphics.Main.start(Main.java:25)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:839)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:483)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:456)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:400)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics@20.0.1/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
    ... 1 more
Exception running application com.example.javapoker.Graphics.Main
```

Note: ignore the null conditions, I deleted the condition so it could give me the stack trace erors.

Comment: Instead of src/main/java/com/example/javapoker/Graphics/GUI.fxml, try placing it in src/main/resources/com/example/javapoker/Graphics/GUI.fxml (that is, change `java` to `resources` in the file path).  I’m assuming your project is a Maven project based on the use of src/main/java.

Comment: The troubleshooting steps for you to follow are in the [duplicate: How do I determine the correct path for FXML files, CSS files, Images, and other resources needed by my JavaFX Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61531317/how-do-i-determine-the-correct-path-for-fxml-files-css-files-images-and-other).

Comment: Hello, one more thing... I do not have a resource folder. Is there a way to successfully access the fxml file with using a resource folder?

Comment: A resource folder is only for build structure and common project layouts, e.g. the recommended [maven standard layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).  Build tools (like maven, gradle or an ide), copy the resources from there by default and place them in the target build directory, usually packaging up the app, into a jar or jlink image.  Once the resources are copied out of the resource directory and placed in the target directory they are no longer in a separate resource directory but in the same directory as the class files.

Comment: So, it is recommended you have a resource folder and put the resources in it, and use a build tool (maven or gradle to assemble your app), and then use getResource to get the resources from your code.  The build tool will take care of making sure in the resources end up in the right place so that the code can access them.  This is explained in the linked duplicate, as well as steps to take to troubleshoot when things go wrong.

Comment: An IDE like [idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/new-project-wizard.html) will create a template project with everything setup in the right place.  Or [openjfx getting started](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) has instructions on setting things up in another environment (e.g. using maven archetypes or the openjfx sample projects).  In your case for instance, openjfx references a `javafx-archetype-fxml` for maven.